# str_to_date function not working in complexe mysql query joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, alias

I have a sql query witch returns the 3 newest formations, but it does'nt work after i have changed the fin_date column type from string to date with specific format:

```
   $today = JFactory::getDate()->toFormat('%d/%m/%Y');
   // echo $today==> 18/12/2018

$query =  "SELECT p.fin_date, pfr.product_name, p.ville"
             ." FROM #__virtuemart_products as p"
             ." LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_products_fr_fr as pfr on pfr.virtuemart_product_id = p.virtuemart_product_id"
             ." WHERE p.published = 1   AND  p.product_parent_id != 0 AND str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= $today "
             ." LIMIT 4 "
             ;
```

even i change it to:

```
$query =  "SELECT str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y'), pfr.product_name, p.ville"
             ." FROM #__virtuemart_products as p"
             ." LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_products_fr_fr as pfr on pfr.virtuemart_product_id = p.virtuemart_product_id"
             ." WHERE p.published = 1   AND  p.product_parent_id != 0 AND str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= $today "
             ." LIMIT 4 "
             ;
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an error message or problem statement. Please give us a clear description of your issue. Also some sample data and expected out would be very useful.

Comment: I want to display the next courses dedicated to students. ie formations with a date> = at the current date. But the end date of each training (fin_date) is stored in the bd as string and when compared with the current date ($ today) of type date in the query. it does not work, rather the str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= $today isn't working, it's the probleme

Comment: ...you still said "isn't working" instead of actually describing the data involved, and the behaviour you see

Comment: this condition is not interprated in the query:  str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= $today. I retrieve a data but this condition is not verified in the query

Comment: "I retrieve a data"..what data, exactly? As I keep saying, show us an example of the input

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a date (the output of `str_to_date`), which will be in `Y-m-d` format internally, to a string in `d/m/Y` format. You need to either create your `$today` variable in `Y-m-d` format using

```
$today = JFactory::getDate()->toFormat('%Y-%m-%d');
```

or convert it inside your query i.e.

```
str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= str_to_date($today,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: $today is in the right format also str_to_date put the p.fin_date in the same format as $today, but this condition str_to_date(p.fin_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= $today  isn't interperate  in the query

Comment: @ArwaHafdhi that's not how `str_to_date` works, it converts a string in the format `%d/%m/%Y` into a date (which is represented internally as e.g. `2018-12-18`). So when you do the comparison, you need to have `$today` in the same format using one of the methods I have given in my answer.